# matlab modem.oqpskmod

Tags: matlab

I wanted to use the following (in MATLAB R2007a)

```
        h = modem.oqpskmod
```

but MATLAB complains that modem is not defined as follows:

```
??? Undefined function or variable 'modem'.

Error in ==> program at 34
h = modem.oqpskmod
```

Is there anything i will have to include, import,... in order to be able to use modem.oqpskmod? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Modem**](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/comm/ref/modem.html) objects were [first introduced in Version 4.0 (R2007b)](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/comm/rn/bq7qlgv-1.html) of the [Communications Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/comm/), and they are now a *class* in the newer versions (with [**oqpskmod**](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/comm/ref/modem.oqpskmod.html) being a method of that class, hence the syntax `modem.oqpskmod`). Since you are using MATLAB Version 7.4 (R2007a), I'm guessing you are also using Version 3.5 of the Communications Toolbox (the version *just before* modem objects were introduced). This would explain why MATLAB is saying that `modem` is undefined.

You can check which version of the Communications Toolbox you are using with the [VER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ver.html) function. Just type `ver` at the command prompt to see a list of the versions of all the installed toolboxes.